# Running 'npm install' in Simple example of redux-form causes ' Cannot find module 'babel-register' error

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to try the simple form example in redux-from (https://github.com/erikras/redux-form). The README.md of the example says

````
## To run locally

```
npm install
npm start
```
````

After I cloned the redux-form project locally, I cd to `examples/simple` and run `npm install`. It failed and throw this exception:

```
> redux-form@6.5.0 prepublish /Users/antkong/wd/redux-form
> npm run test && npm run clean && npm run build


> redux-form@6.5.0 test /Users/antkong/wd/redux-form
> mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --recursive "src/**/__tests__/*" --require src/__tests__/setup.js

module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:337:3
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:329:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node5/5.11.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v5.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! redux-form@6.5.0 test: `mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --recursive "src/**/__tests__/*" --require src/__tests__/setup.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-form@6.5.0 test script 'mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --recursive "src/**/__tests__/*" --require src/__tests__/setup.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the redux-form package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --recursive "src/**/__tests__/*" --require src/__tests__/setup.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs redux-form
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls redux-form
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/antkong/wd/redux-form/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/antkong/wd/redux-form
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node5/5.11.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! redux-form@6.5.0 prepublish: `npm run test && npm run clean && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-form@6.5.0 prepublish script 'npm run test && npm run clean && npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the redux-form package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run test && npm run clean && npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs redux-form
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls redux-form
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/antkong/wd/redux-form/examples/simple/npm-debug.log
```

How can I fix it? I am using

osx 10.12.1
npm 2.10.6
node 5.11.1

Answer (score 0):

The README.md of `example/simple` leaves out a bit of details. I need to run `npm install` first at the root level of the repo before I cd to `simple` and run npm `install` there.